# Animate line graph line

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

Its a simple line graph using D3

I'd like to animate the line from left to right.

Cant find many of this or anything explaing the best way

The actual graph will have a bar chart as well so I cant animate and white block on top to show the line

Comment: what a simple search with your favorite search engine can find: https://bl.ocks.org/pjsier/28d1d410b64dcd74d9dab348514ed256

Comment: This one of the examples I found, but I can't get it to work in my example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart-n7qqas?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

Comment: Did you check the code in the example @rioV8 referred to? The transition is applied using `stroke-dasharray` and not to the `d` of the `path`. It works very well indeed: here's a fork: [stackblitz.com/edit/...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart-mgaguj?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts)

Comment: @Shashank : the tween dash can be simplified. What is the use of `i`? See my edit of my answer.

Comment: @rioV8 True that. @ttmt: Here's [Mike's Stroke-dash-interpolation example with explanation](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592) you can refer to as well along with exclusion of not-so-necessary `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why messing around with a tween function, interpolators and `this`?

The easiest and most common solution is simply setting the `stroke-dasharray` and the `stroke-dashoffset` for the total length...

```
var totalLength = thisLine.node().getTotalLength();

thisLine.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
```

And then changing it with a simple transition:

```
thisLine.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

No need for tweening the `stroke-dasharray`.

Here is the forked code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart-3hpaje?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

Answer (score 2):

It is all a `this` problem.

```
  private transition(path) {
    var that = this;
      path.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", that.tweenDash);
  }

  private tweenDash() {
    var l = this.getTotalLength(),
        i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
    return function (t) { return i(t); };
  }

  private drawLine(linedata:any){
    // ....

    var p = this.lineArea.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline(linedata))
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      //.call(that.transition)
      ;
    this.transition(p);
  }
```

**Edit**

Why do we need `i`?

This is the same

```
  private tweenDash() {
    var l = this.getTotalLength();
    return d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  }
```

Comment: Ah! The `this` problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback#answer-20279485) is a fantastic answer/response to the `this` problem.