# D3 - axis only show values from 0-1

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-positioned-months-pmsptg?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

Its a stacked bar chart with a dual axis and a line chart in top.

I can't work out why but the right axis that is the line data has stopped working and only shows value from 0-1

I've been looking at this for hours and the code looks exactly like other examples of line chart I've done like - https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart-tbjdiw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideNavigation=1

Can anyone see what I've done to break this.

Comment: You still have the fundamental error you had in your previous stachblitz regarding the transition chaining, you now have resolved it with a settimeout call (you removed that question). Add console.log statements in your `drawAxis` and your `drawLine` functions and see the order of them. Why do you draw 2 identical xAxis?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to do this. I have the second xAxis because i had the second yAxis for the rightAxis. I was going to refactor and remove the second xAxis

Answer (score 1):

I feel it's a good practice to append the `<g>` for the axes first and then once the domains are set, you call them. Relevant changes made:

1. Re-ordered:

   ```
   this.drawAxis();
   this.createStack(this.data);
   ```
2. Calling axes once the domains are set:

   ```
   this.y0.domain([0, +d3.max(this.stackedSeries, function (d: any) {
      return d3.max(d, (d: any) => {
         return d[1]
      })
   })]);
   this.chart.select('g.y0-axis').call(d3.axisLeft(this.y0));
   ```
3. Removing "four" from the keys as it doesn't exist in the data:

   ```
     .keys(['one', 'two', 'three'])
   ```
4. Included the `stroke-dasharray` transition to the line from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874281/animate-line-graph-line)

   ```
   var totalLength = thisLine.node().getTotalLength();

   thisLine.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);

   thisLine.transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
   ```

Here's a fork of your code with the above changes:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-positioned-months-vtb2zr?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

Comment: point 3. should have been detected by himself because it generates a lot of NaN errors in the console, not the stackblitz but from the browser.